# Compare two arrays and show the items of the first array that have the key from the second array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, mapping

I have two different arrays, one that has all the data that i'm using on a list and the another one that just has values from a filter that i allow the user to choose. So my first array is this one:

```
messages=[
{id:1, description:'abc', status:'SENT'},
{id:2, description:'hello', status:'CANCELED'},
{id:1, description:'bye', status:'SENT'}];
```

And my second array is this one:

```
items = ["SENT", "CLOSED", "RECEIVED"];
```

I have this hook to set the data also, that right now has all of it:

```
const [messageData, setMessageData] = useState([]);
```

And what i'm trying to do is to set on my hook the objects of the first array that have as a status the same value of one of the items on my second array (items) so i can later do a map of messageData on my render, in this case i have to render the first and third record of my messages array because they have a status of 'SENT' and that value is on my items array.

The thing is, i don't know how to compare and get those results, i tried doing a map of the message's array and filtering the items that had as a state one os the items array values, like this:

```
let search = [];
messages
.filter((option) => {
 return(
  option.value.status = items.value
 )
})
.map((option) => {
   search.push(option);
})
   setMessageData(search);
```

But this is not working and im not sure how to solve it, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your `messages` items have no `value` property, only a `status` property

Comment: Also you are using `=` for comparison, use `==`

Comment: I was using ==, but i might have deleted by error when i was pasting my code, and yes, the items.value thing was wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good situation for `reduce()`

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Calling `reduce()` on the items array iterates over each element and accumulates the results of the logic passed.

In the example below the accumulator `acc` is initialized as an empty array by passing `[]` as the second argument in the `reduce()` call.

```js
const messages=[
{id:1, description:'abc', status:'SENT'},
{id:2, description:'hello', status:'CANCELED'},
{id:1, description:'bye', status:'SENT'}];

const items = ["SENT", "CLOSED", "RECEIVED"];

// iterate over each 'status' in the items array
let search = items.reduce((acc, status) => {

  // retrieve objects from the messages array that match
  const matches = messages.filter(message => message.status === status);
  
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    // if matches were found concat the returned array with the accumulator
    acc = acc.concat(matches);
  }
  
  // return the accumulator to be used in the next iteration
  return acc;
  
}, []);

console.log(search)
```

---

**Turn it into a function**

In response to your comment about receiving differing results I've turned it into a function to easily test results from different `statusArray`s and the `reduce()` call is working as expected.

```js
const messages=[
{id:1, description:'abc', status:'SENT'},
{id:2, description:'hello', status:'CANCELED'},
{id:1, description:'bye', status:'RECEIVED'},
{id:1, description:'xyz', status:'SENT'},
{id:2, description:'hi', status:'SENT'},
{id:1, description:'bye again', status:'RECEIVED'}];


function filterMessagesByStatus(statusArray) {
  if (!Array.isArray(statusArray)) return;  
  
  return statusArray.reduce((acc, status) => {
    const matches = messages.filter(message => message.status === status);
    if (matches.length > 0) {
      acc = acc.concat(matches);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []); 
}

console.log(filterMessagesByStatus(["SENT", "CANCELED", "RECEIVED"]));
console.log(filterMessagesByStatus(["SENT"]));
console.log(filterMessagesByStatus(["CANCELED", "RECEIVED"]));
console.log(filterMessagesByStatus(["SENT", "CANCELED", "RECEIVED"]));
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! thank you so much for the corrections and also explaining every step

Comment: I have a question though, because when i search with items with the status SEND it shows me the two objects, then i search for CANCELED and shows me nothing, and if i go back and choose SEND again it keeps showing me 0 results. How can i keep that from happening?

Comment: Updated my answer to test different search arrays and it is working as expected. I can only guess that maybe you searched 'SEND' instead of 'SENT'. Also `filter` is case sensitive.